# prevent multiple query PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey i am using a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO likes( 
     likes_memory_id, 
     likes_owner_id, 
     likes_like
 ) VALUES (
     :likes_memory_id, 
     :likes_owner_id, 
     :likes_like)
```

when ever an user click the like button, this query adds a new row. so this query allows to like multiple time.
I want to prevent a row with the same owner_id and same memory_id.
To prevent this i may use a select statement and I might succeed it in two queries but I am sure that there is a better way to do it. (I made research about if not exists statement but i didnt understand too much ) How do I avoid multiple likes only with a SQL query?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent? A row with the same owner_id and the same comment_id?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson good question it wasnt clear i fixed it. you are right same owner_id and same memory_id dont worry about the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to create a unique index on your columns which you want unique;

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_mem_own ON likes(
  likes_memory_id, likes_owner_id
);
```

...and insert likes using `INSERT IGNORE`, which will insert the value if it's not prevented by the index, otherwise just ignore it;

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO likes( 
     likes_memory_id, 
     likes_owner_id, 
     likes_like
 ) VALUES (
     :likes_memory_id, 
     :likes_owner_id, 
     :likes_like)
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b58fc3/1). Note that the duplicate row is not inserted.

Comment: If the owner_id is unique, can he like another post?

Comment: @suyilmaz Yes, it's only the combination userid+post that is unique. If you look at the SQLfiddle, you can see that user 1 likes 2 different posts without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this programmatically by checking if the user has already liked the post. One way would be to set a "liked" flag on the page somewhere and disable the like button when the current user has already liked  post.

You could either check before your insert by running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE likes_comment_id = [comment_id] AND likes_owner_id = [owner_id]
```

If the query returns no results, execute your `INSERT` otherwise don't. You can also run this at page load so that you can mark the liked comments and liked comments cannot then be liked again.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i was thinking the same. But then i thought maybe there is a better way to do it. we will see:)

Comment: You could also create the unique key for the entries by concatenating the id of the liking user with the comment id (i.e. 3014567, where 301 is the user doing the like and 4567 is the comment id) and pairing it with a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE key=key it will do nothing because the key is the same.

Comment: Just a thought, though, if a user clicks it again shouldn't that then initiate an "unlike" and actually remove that entry from the database?